# PyTorch replace `nan` with column-wise maximum

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, torch

I have a tensor of size `[n, c]` having some `nan` values.
I want to replace the `nan` values with the max. value in the column that it lies.
I can think of a solution, but it consists of `for` loops. Is there a vectorized/pytorch-ic way of doing this?

Example:

```
Input:
[[0.25, nan, 0.10],
 [0.75, 0.80, nan],
 [0.00, nan, 0.30],
 [nan, 0.00, 0.85]]

Output:
[[0.25, 0.80, 0.10],
 [0.75, 0.80, 0.85],
 [0.00, 0.80, 0.30],
 [0.75, 0.00, 0.85]]
```

Comment: `Input.nan_to_num_(-torch.inf); torch.where(torch.isneginf(Input), torch.max(Input, dim=0).values, Input)`, there has to be a nicer alternative.